# Leaves of Alcea turning white after planting

Tags: flowers, leaves

We grew about 100 Alceas from seeds and they did great. Two days ago we planted them and now some of their leaves are turning white. What could be the cause of this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its  not the sun as the leaves would be burned not bleached, Its possibly a manganese deficiency, often linked with iron problems and soils over pH of 7.5 , just feed them with a plant tonic with both elements in it. But as Stephie says two days? perhaps the problems came in with the compost they where grown in? Or the water in the water table did something to the roots? but then again they would show signs of drowning? Its not the sun, definitely nothing to do with the sun, the damage looks very much like a kind of deficiency, something very much wrong with the plant rather than something external affecting the plant. I still go with something to do with nutrients, the only way is try a plant in a shady position and see what happens? rule one thing out at a time.

Comment: In two days? That sounds rather quick?

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, it might be something wrong with the seeds or even the soil we grew them in. There were a few left in the tray, and they have the same issue while standing in a more shaded location. It will be a step by step elimination process to find the real issue.

Answer (score 3):

It could be a reaction to the sun, since you changed the location of the plants. I don't know if they receive more sunlight now after the translocation? Were they indoor before?

The best way is to let the plants adjust to direct sunlight first, in small steps.

Comment: That has to be the case indeed. We grew them behind the house where they only get morning sun. Now they are in front of the house where they are in the sun from one until the end of the day. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I think your plants will survive, however you could try to shade them in the mid of the day with an umbrella/sun screen or something, and give them gradually more light each day. Good luck!